# I'm having a problem viewing the Youtube video

Tags: single, youtube, post-content

I'm having a problem viewing the Youtube video.

In my single-custom I am using:

```
<? Php
echo wpautop ($post-> post_content);
?>
```

And when I put the Youtube link he is not showing the video but only his link.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the_content function to process embeds.
Another way is to apply the_content filter.

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content' );
```

Comment: You are welcome. Mark my answer as the solution, please